# jQuery easyui datagrid page reset

Tags: datagrid, jquery-easyui

I am using easyui to load some data in datagrid. The grid is placed in a jsp page and then initialized as soon as the page renders, using the function below. I want the grid to load with specific page number and page size, this is why I set
      pageNumber: selectedPage,
      pageSize: selectedSize,
What happens however is that the grid auto-resets: a call with the correct page configuration is made to the server (Spring MVC) and immediately afterwards another one is made that resets the grid (default values are page=1 and page size=10). So I see for 1 sec the correct page and then the grid moves back to page 1. When I tried to cut the second call no data appeared at all, while when I added another call (a third one), a fourth one immediately came to reset it.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

```
    <table id="dg" style="width: 940px; display:none;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th
                    data-options="field:'publicationNumber',width:134,sortable:true"
                    formatter="formatPubNumber"><fmt:message key='page.search.form.publicationNo' /></th>
                <th data-options="field:'rightType',width:134,sortable:true"><fmt:message key='page.search.form.ipcRightType' /></th>
                <th data-options="field:'publicationDate',width:124,sortable:true"><fmt:message key='page.search.form.date.publicationDate' /></th>
                <th data-options="field:'ipcClass',width:124,sortable:true"><fmt:message key='page.search.form.ipcCode' /></th>
                <th data-options="field:'applicantHolder',width:124,sortable:true"><fmt:message key='page.search.form.applicant' /></th>
                <th data-options="field:'status',width:114,sortable:true"><fmt:message key='page.search.form.status' /></th>
                <th data-options="field:'uri',hidden:true"></th>
                <th data-options="field:'id',hidden:true"></th>
                <th data-options="field:'format',hidden:true"></th>
                <th data-options="field:'applicationNumber',hidden:true"></th>
                <th data-options="field:'action',width:50" formatter="actionStarFormatter">
                    <fmt:message key='page.search.form.grid.action' /></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>


$("#dg").datagrid(
        {
            url : '<c:url value="/search" />',
            scrollbarSize:0,
            fitColumns : true,
            singleSelect : false,
            pagination : true,
            onBeforeLoad : function(data){
                rowIndexToFill = null;
            },
            onLoadSuccess : function(data) {
                  gridDisplay();
            },
            onLoadError : function(result) {
                // empty grid
                $("#dg").datagrid('loadData', {
                    patents: {totalElements : 0, content : []}
                });
                //Remove Refresh button from datagrid pagination 
                $(".pagination-load").closest('td').remove();
            },
            // highlight previously selected row
            rowStyler : function(rowIndex, row) {
                    // do stuff here
            },
            pageNumber: selectedPage,
            pageSize: selectedSize,
            view:groupview,
            groupField:'id',
            groupFormatter:function(value,rows){  
                return rows[0].title;  
            },
            loadFilter : function(result) {
                  // do stuff here
            }
  });
```